# Unapproving suggested edit?

Tags: support, status-completed

I accidentally approved this tag wiki edit - https://gis.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/34366 ([vrt](https://gis.stackexchange.com/tags/vrt/info)). I was dithering between skipping and rejecting as while it is technically correct (VRTs can be mosaics) it is very incomplete and as such is a little misleading.

How do I unapprove my approval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would not try to unapprove it, even if it were possible, because I think it will be easier for you to simply edit the tag wiki after its current approval cycle (which is normally very quick) is complete.